# Como ler arquivo txt e montar json php?

Tags: php

Estou precisando de um código para ler um arquivo **.txt** onde a primeira linha do arquivo tem que ficar dentro de um **array** chamado `Cabecalho` e o restante das linhas ficará dentro de um **array** com o nome `Dados`, e depois vou usar `json_encode()` para montar um **json**. Porém para montar os **array** preciso quebrar as strings do **txt** para cada valor ficar dentro de sua determinada chave.

```
<?php
$arquivo = fopen('COBST_BGM1_03_070119P_MOV.txt', 'r');

if ($arquivo == false)
    die('Não foi possível abrir o arquivo.');
$lista = fgets($arquivo);

$dadox['Cabecalho'][] = array(
    'codigo_banco' => substr($lista, 0, 3),
    'lote:' => substr($lista, 3, 4),
    'tipo_registro:' => substr($lista, 7, 1),
    'reservado:' => substr($lista, 8, 8),
    'tipo_incricao:' => substr($lista, 16, 1),
    'n_incricao:' => substr($lista, 17, 15),
    'agencia:' => substr($lista, 32, 4),
    'digito_agencia:' => substr($lista, 36, 1),
    'n_conta:' => substr($lista, 37, 9),
    'digito_verificador:' => substr($lista, 46, 1),
    'reservado_2:' => substr($lista, 47, 5),
    'codigo_beneficiario:' => substr($lista, 52, 9),
    'reservado_3:' => substr($lista, 61, 11),
    'nome_empresa:' => substr($lista, 72, 30),
    'nome_banco:' => substr($lista, 102, 30),
    'reservado_4:' => substr($lista, 132, 10),
    'codigo_remessa_retorno:' => substr($lista, 142, 1),
    'data:' => substr($lista, 143, 8),
    'reservado_5:' => substr($lista, 151, 6),
    'n_sequencial:' => substr($lista, 157, 6),
    'n_versao:' => substr($lista, 163, 3),
    'reservado_6:' => substr($lista, 166, 74)
);



header('Content-Type: application/json');

$dados = array(
    $dadox
);


$json_str = json_encode($dados, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);



echo "$json_str";

fclose($arquivo);
?>
```

Comment: O que mudou da sua pergunta anterior para esta? Não consegui entender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você utilizar o comando FILE, cada linha do seu arquivo vai ser armazenada num array. Desta forma, você consegue separar o conteúdo em dois array. De acordo com o que eu entendi, ficaria desta forma:

```
<?php
$file = file("meu_arquivo_texto.txt");
$total_linhas  = count($file);
$Dados = array();
for($x=0; $x<$total_linhas; $x++) { 
    if ($x==0){
        $Cabecalho = $file[$x];
    } else {
        $Dados[] = $file[$x];
    }
}

$resultados = array($Cabecalho, $Dados);
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$json_str = json_encode($resultados, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json_str;
?>
```